# Периодичное выполнение запроса

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Подскажите, а можно ли при помощи js выгребать данные из базы потсгрес с некой периодичностью?

Comment: Если кратко: можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, ответ таков

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    show();  
    setInterval('show()',60000);  
});
```

В функцию `show();` пихаем обращение к базе в виде `ajax`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ajax.php?val="+val,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data)
{
```